# Unable to get value stored in memory using Indirect addressing mode

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I have a below assembly code:

**indirect1.s**

```
.section .data
t1: 
.long 5
.section .text
.globl _start
_start: 
movl $t1, %ecx          #we are passing the address to %ecx
movl $5, %eax           #we are passing value 5 to %eax
movl (%ecx), %ebx   #Using indirect addressing mode we are getting the value from t1 and passing it to ebx
addl %eax, %ebx     # add the values in %eax, %ebx and store it in %ebx
movl $1, %eax       # call exit program
int $0x80       # Call Master Bruce Wayne
```

when the above program is run, I get the value 10 as expected

```
[ashok@localhost asm-32]$ as indirect1.s -gstabs+ -o indirect1.o
[ashok@localhost asm-32]$ ld indirect1.o -o indirect1
[ashok@localhost asm-32]$ ./indirect1 
[ashok@localhost asm-32]$ echo $?
10
```

Modified the above program to eliminate %ecx register:

**indirect2.s**

```
.section .data
t1: 
.long 5
.section .text
.globl _start
_start: 
    movl $t1, %ebx      # we are passing the address to %ebx
    movl $5, %eax       # we are passing value 5 to %eax
    addl %eax, (%ebx)   # add the values in %eax, %ebx and store it in %ebx
    movl $1, %eax       # call exit program
    int $0x80       # Call Master Bruce Wayne
```

When i run the above program , i don't get the expected output ,i.e 10 and i seem to 
get the address stored in %ebx

```
[ashok@localhost asm-32]$ as indirect2.s -gstabs+ -o indirect2.o
[ashok@localhost asm-32]$ ld indirect2.o -o indirect2
[ashok@localhost asm-32]$ ./indirect2
[ashok@localhost asm-32]$ echo $?
136
```

What i am doing wrong in indirect2.s program.

Comment: What are you doing wrong? Well, `ebx` doesn't contain the desired value, because you didn't put it in there. (Do you know what `int $0x80` does and what its requirements are?)

Comment: @KerrekSB Thanks for your comment, when i specified `addl %eax, (%ebx)`, i am assuming the address stored in ebx will be used to fetch the value "5"

Comment: @KerrekSB, int $0x80 calls kernel to run exit system call which which should give the status of exit based on the contents of register %ebx, which should be 10.

Comment: Right, but you never put 10 into ebx. `addl` stores the result in the second operand.

Comment: @KerrekSB  okay, So in instruction `addl %eax, (%ebx)` doesn't (%ebx) is the second argument.

Comment: @KerrekSB okay i get what you are saying `addl %eax, (%ebx)` the second operand will never have 10 because the second operand is being used to reference memory address.

Comment: Don't overthink it: The second operand of your `add` is *not* `%ebx`, that's all that matters. You never write to `%ebx` again after the first instruction.

Comment: @KerrekSB Thanks a lot for your comments, I understood the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
movl $t1, %ebx      # ebx = address of t1
movl $5, %eax       # eax = 5
addl (%ebx), %eax   # eax += (ebx)
movl %eax, %ebx     # exit value
movl $1, %eax       # exit()
int $0x80
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, to make your second example work:

```
.section .data
t1: 
.long 5
.section .text
.globl _start
_start: 
    movl $t1, %ebx      # we are passing the address to %ebx
    movl $5, %eax       # we are passing value 5 to %eax
    addl %eax, (%ebx)   # add the values in %eax, %ebx and store it in %ebx
    movl (%ebx), %ebx   # THE FORGOTTEN INSTRUCTION (read result back into %ebx)
    movl $1, %eax       # call exit program
    int $0x80       # Call Master Bruce Wayne
```

What happened is your initial version of indirect2 printed out the relative address of `$t1` which is what was in `%ebx` when the program exited.